# Firewall blocking uploading a file in my filezilla server

Tags: c#, filezilla

I am trying to setup a filezilla server. I have followed the instructions from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/). I have write a simple c# script in order to upload data to server. My code is the following:

```
static void UploadFile(string filepath)
{
    string m_FtpHost = "ftp://ip:port/";
    string m_FtpUsername = "user";
    string m_FtpPassword = "pass";

    // Get an instance of WebClient
    WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    // parse the ftp host and file into a uri path for the upload
    Uri uri = new Uri(m_FtpHost + new FileInfo(filepath).Name);
    // set the username and password for the FTP server
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(m_FtpUsername, m_FtpPassword);
    // upload the file asynchronously, non-blocking.

    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", filepath);
}
```

When I am running that script from the same computer everything is working fine. When I trid to run the same script from another computer of the same lan I got issues. The file doesnt sent it properly. When I turn off the firewall however the upload is happerning normally. Any idea how to get over the firewall?

Comment: Open the FTP port in the firewall.

Comment: I have opened  it from the server side. I have to do the same fo the other pc in which i am running the script?

Comment: No, on the server.  http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-allow-ftp-traffic-through-windows-8-8-1-windows-7-firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the Windows asks the user to give permission to a program when it tries to use any port (the Windows get's a pop out asking to allow or disallow the program from using the port )   ... 
I'm not sure how to do it but I found a link ...

> I'm not sure what conditions need to be met to expose this dialog, I
>   would assume an application that attempts to open a listening port on
>   a vanilla Windows instance should always display this dialog. Why
>   don't you try adding your application to the 'authorized applications'
>   list, or opening the port manually using the Windows Firewall COM
>   interop (NetFwTypeLib)?
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

quoted from alexw